# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, chai, hardhat

I have created 2 TESTS --

In 2nd TEST, I have enclosed owner, addr1, addr2 in `[]` as per the Official Hardhat Documentation, like this `const [owner,addr1,addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();`,
But the problem is when I use `[]` bracket, it shows me the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')` and the test also failed,

Here is the Code --->

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
// const { ethers } = require('hardhat');


describe('Token contract', function () {
    //1st TEST

    it('Deployment should assign the total supply of the tokens to the owner', async function () {
        const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
        

        const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token');

        const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

        const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
        
        expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
    });

    //2nd TEST

    it('Should Transfer Tokens between accounts', async function () {
        
        const [owner,addr1,addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
        

        const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token');

        const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

        //Transfer 10 tokens from Owner to addr1
        await hardhatToken.transfer(addr1.address,10);
        expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address).to.equal(10));

        //Transfer 5 tokens from addr1 to addr2
        await hardhatToken.connect(addr1).transfer(addr2.address,5);
        expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr2.address).to.equal(5))
    });
});
```

But if U see in the 1st TEST, I haven't used `[]`, for owner, so the test passed.
Below is the Official Hardhat documentation if U want to check the code --->

https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html

Please help me to solve this Problem
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuDPL.png)

Comment: Your parentheses in test 2 are wrong. It's `expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address)).to.equal(10);` and `expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr2.address)).to.equal(5)`

Comment: Thank U so much Brother , It worked successfully now. Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the parenthesis around the `expect` calls in the second test correctly. You're accessing `.to` on the number returned by `.balanceOf`.

Replace with:

```js
expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr1.address)).to.equal(10);
// ...
expect(await hardhatToken.balanceOf(addr2.address)).to.equal(5);
```

Comment: Thank U so much Brother ,  I don't know, How am I unable to observe this mistake.  Thank U so much !!

Comment: Please don't write an answer for typos. It's a close reason